# Check if the user adding a reaction has a role

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to check if the user reacting to a message has a role or not, so that if the user dont have a rank the bot will ignore the rest of the command, but I dont know how.

example: if a user with the admin rank reacted with :eggsa: emoji, the bot would continue with the command, but if i only had member rank the bot would ignore me.

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', reaction => {
    const eggsa = client.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === "eggsa");
    if (reaction.emoji.name === 'eggsa') {
        const message = reaction.message;
        const kanal = reaction.message.guild.channels.find('name', 'sitater');
        var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(reaction.message.content)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(reaction.message.author.username, reaction.message.author.avatarURL)
        kanal.send({embed});
    }
});
```

the code works in this stage, only everyone can use it

I would be really grateful if someone could help me >:)

Comment: You should show your attempt at doing this and then we can help, we aren't going to do it all for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [messageReactionAdd docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) you can see that along with the reaction, you can also get the user which added the reaction. So instead of

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', reaction => {
```

You'd have

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
```

So then you have the user and which is of type [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User). Because the `user` isn't of type GuildMember you first need to fetch the correct Guild member before you can check his/her role.

The easiest way to do this is by getting the Message to which the reaction was added with `const msg = reaction.message;`. Then you can get the guild from the message with `const guild = msg.guild;`. Now you can access the guild members with `const guildMembers = guild.members;`. Lastly you'd need to find the correct member with `const guildMember = guildMembers.get(user.id);`.

Now that you have your Guild Member you can access his/her [Roles](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles) and thus check whether he/she has or does not have a certain role

Comment: If you have an ID use .get()